# Creating 'Appointment' entity in Dynamics 365 indirectly that would create meeting in Teams

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-teams, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate, appointment

I am trying to create an Appointment entity record through Power Automate Flow based on Dataverse Add new Record trigger on our custom entity.

We have mailboxes set to Server Side Synchronization.

Emails go out fine
When I create an appointment, it shows up in outlook/teams calendar but even though I set:
IsOnlineMeeting = 1
MeetingType = Teams Meeting

It does not generate 'Online Meeting'. There is no JOIN option.
Meeting shows up like offline meeting.

If I try creating an Appointment from Dynamics UI and set 'Team Meeting' toggle to yes then it generates Online meeting with JOIN option.

I compared attributes for both records and only difference I see is,
flow generated records does not have following values set:

1. Online Meeting id
2. Online Meeting Chat ID
3. Online Meeting Join URL

The one that was created through Dynamics UI has these values.
How do I set these values for my Flow Generated Appointment?

Basically I want to create teams meeting from Power Automate Flow.

We have tried Teams Connector but issue with it is meeting 'organizer' stays flow owner all the time. This is not a desirable option. 'Use Invokers' Connection' option does not work with this connector (resets automatically on save). Have raised an issue with Microsoft. However they are taking their own sweet time.

Tried creating appointment through Plugin as well. Same issue as Power Automate.
Tried creating appointment through traditional workflow. Teams meeting is created here. However you cannot add multiple people as attendees here. Only takes 1

So we are kind of stuck.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Reshma

Answer (score 0):

Creating Appointments requires the following fields:

- `Subject`
- `Organizer`
- `Regarding`
- `IsOnlineMeeting=true`
- `OnlineMeetingType=TeamsMeeting`

[image: Create Invite Programmatically from CRM]